# FBMQ Python Facebook messenger bot postback

Tags: python, facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

While doing a facebook chat bot, i've encountered an error that postbacks only works 1 time, after that i have to refresh the page for postback to work.

here's my code:

`page.show_starting_button("START_PAYLOAD")`

`@page.handle_postback
def received_postback(event):
    sender_id = event.sender_id
    recipient_id = event.recipient_id
    time_of_postback = event.timestamp`

```
payload = event.postback_payload

print("Received postback for user %s and page %s with payload '%s' at %s"
      % (sender_id, recipient_id, payload, time_of_postback))

page.send(sender_id, "Postback called")`
```

Thank you in advance